# Can I make the mouse pointer smoother like Mac in ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

Moving mouse flickers all the time. Can I somehow make the mouse pointer movement smoother like we used to see in Apple Mac? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Intel Core i5 powered PC with 8GB of Ram.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: More specifically, what system _are_ you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 on a Intel Core i5 powered PC with 8GB of Ram.